# What are these green colored resistors?

Tags: resistors, components

My old multimeter, with all through hole components had an accident (I was measuring current on the 10A unfused range and then decided to check the voltage of the a lead acid battery) with one large carbon resistor glowing and melting and another through hold low value 1 Watt component suffering failure. Everything works apart from current measurement.

Can anyone identify this resistor (I cannot measure it as it has fused).
[image]

I have checked various sources and this value doesn't appear in any of the E... series. I think that the colors are blue silver white and gold and suspect that is is a sub 1 Ohm value part as it was used as a shunt for < 0.5 Amp measurements but I have never seen a dark green resistor before (I think that this would be early 90's vintage).

Comment: Are you sure it even is a resistor? In any case, if its part of a range switching mechanism you might be able to work out its value by reverse engineering parts of the schematic and comparing. If you suspect its a shunt, you can put a decade/pot in place and run a current through it and adjust until the meter shows the right values.

Comment: I'd be surprised if anyone can give much insight from the image. Find the service manual for your multimeter. Chances increases the older it is.

Comment: I was thinking that it was an indcutor, but the markings didn't match any chokes/indcutor markings either. The second band is silver and the last gold.  Silver should not be in the second position if gold is in the last. I cannot get any value for the component as a choke nor resistor.

Comment: Hard to tell, but could it be brown-orange-silver-blue, that is 0,13 Ohm with 0,25% tolerance?

Comment: What is the country of origin of this device?

Comment: You can place a experimental resistor in your   injured DVM .I will ballpark a starting value .Say that the amps range was 300mA DC and if your lowest volt setting was say 300mV DC then it is not rocket science to put a 1 ohm resistor in and see how it goes by checking currents with known loads .When you find another DVM then you can check your ballpark resistor for calibration and adjust if necessary .

Comment: The user manual might give some information on the size of the sense resistor if it lists the burden voltage at some current. (usually max burden at max current)

Comment: If @Arsenal yields a dead end: these shunts are linear circuits. So estimate, and try a resistor substitute, applying a 0.25A current. If you get less than half-scale reading, your estimate was too small - try a proportionally larger substitute resistor. You should be able to successively approximate the right value after three or four tries (if your first guess was reasonable).

Comment: Can you find a R or L on the pcb? Put the item in a small box, fill it with `Uhu Hart` or Epoxy and polish it down until you see the inner parts and send us a picture. In the meantime have a look here: http://www.vishay.com/inductors/color-code-calculator/

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone. The picture was taken by a cheap optical microscope - essential for reading packaging information these days. I believe that the component was a high accuracy 1 Ohm resistor. I scraped off the packaging and remove the legs and the caps to which they were attached and measured its resitance. I didn't bother grinding it down as the entire package was made of a solid metal. Were I to  guess that it was of high tolerance and probably not very common.

Answer (score 3):

Replace it with a resistor you have that is closest to 0.1Ω

Or try 13.6" of 24 gauge wire.

Take a 100mA current reading and see how close the it is to the actual current.  Ballpark will do, just want to know the magnitude.

From there it's just simple arithmetic.

Is the current 10x?  Or 1x.

If you need to buy a resistor, try a 0.01Ω and a 0.1Ω  Tolerance is up to you, smaller is always better.

The first band is likely brown because a 1 makes sense for a current sense resistor value.

The second may be silver where most of it has flaked off.

So my guess is 0.01Ω

0.01Ω is the most common resistor in that range so would be the most likely value for a current sense resistor.

Answer (score 1):

> **How about 0.19Ω 0.25% ?**

Yes I agree

```
Brown White Silver (space)  Blue
  1     9    x0.01          0.25%
```

thus 19x0.01 =0.19 Ω

[image]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5hyCt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Hard to tell from component without schematic, but I would expect 1A limit. 10A would need a much larger >=5W part.

Comment: Generally, I'd agree.  But what on earth would something else than a resistor do in the "business end" of a multimeter?  A MOV, TVS or fuse perhaps, but I've never seen those in a resistor package.

Comment: i agree  ..... now that I see multimeter